# How to convert VARCHAR to BLOB in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, blob, varchar

I need to convert a MySQL column to use BLOB instead of VARCHAR that's used to store encrypted data.

I can find all sorts of posts of how to convert from BLOB to VARCHAR, but cannot find anything for going from VARCHAR to BLOB.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out by using:

```
alter table users change email email blob
```

Comment: +1 for returning with the solution. `email` seems to be the column name: [ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 BLOB;](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html)